# Recycle bin for Android that can store deleted messages,videos, files etc

Tags: android

I want to develop a `Recycle bin` application for android platform. For this I want some ideas so that I can start this project.I want to know how can I design an efficient Recycle bin that can store deleted messages,videos, mp3's, other files etc. I just refer this article [How can I implement “recycle bin” functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072828/how-can-i-implement-recycle-bin-functionality), can I use this way  in android or please suggest  is there any other alternate way?.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in a 3rd party application in a way that would be binding on existing apps.

- You could do it by building functionality and persuading other app creators to hand things off to you rather than deleting them.
- You could do it for literal files (videos, mp3, etc) by modifying the android system to move things to a recycle bin instead of deleting them, but this would not impact database objects like messages
- You could modify the Android system's sqlite database library to put deleted messages somewhere, but the original apps wouldn't be able to access the deleted messages, unless those apps were rebuilt with recycle bin knowlege.

There are also a fair number of privacy/security concerns with your idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about that link? can i follow the idea for literal files?